# xero.apiCallback is not a function

Tags: node.js, xero-api

I am getting an error in my xero code. It says, xero.apiCallback is not a function. The other functions in xero seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');

const XeroRouter = express.Router();

const {  XeroClient } = require('xero-node');

const { TokenSet } = require('openid-client');

const client_id = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirectUrl = process.env.REDIRECT_URI;
const scopes = "openid profile email accounting.settings accounting.reports.read accounting.journals.read accounting.contacts accounting.attachments accounting.transactions offline_access";

const xero = new XeroClient({
    clientId: client_id,
    clientSecret: client_secret,
    redirectUris: [redirectUrl],
    scopes: scopes.split(" "),
});

if ( !client_secret || !redirectUrl) {
    throw Error('Environment Variables not all set - please check your .env file in the project root or create one!')
}


XeroRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl();

        res.redirect(consentUrl);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(e.status || 500);
        console.log(e);
    }
});


XeroRouter.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {

    let tokenSet = await xero.apiCallback(req.url);

    console.log(req.url); //This has value
    console.log(tokenSet); // this returns TokenSet {}


});

module.exports = XeroRouter;
```

I am not sure why apiCallback is not working but it says it does in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and eventually got it working, i had to actually look at the code for the node module to work out what was going on.

You need to explicitly set the openIdClient on construction of XeroClient and it worked for me.

Change your constructor to look like below and it should work.

```
const xero = new XeroClient({
    clientId: client_id,
    clientSecret: client_secret,
    redirectUris: [redirectUrl],
    openIdClient: TokenSet,
    scopes: scopes.split(" "),
});
```